# What type does fwrite() returns?

Tags: php, return, fwrite

On the php manual we can read:

> **fwrite()** returns the number of bytes written

Ok... but what kind of thing is "number of bytes written"?

Binary string? Binary number? Stream? Int?

I'm a little bit lost here.

Regards

Comment: doesn't simple `echo` answer your question?

Comment: In this case, however, I learned that we are able to see the return value on php manual, in a place that I never paid that much attention. Always valuable to ask. Always. :)

Comment: it's side effect, but it doesn't answer my question. why can't you just get this value, print it out and see.

Comment: Because I didn't recall that. I'm not used to programming work-flow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php):

> Description
>
> ```
> int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )
> ```

It returns an int on success, as indicated by the type name just before the function name.  It returns **FALSE** on error:

> **fwrite()** returns the number of bytes written, or **FALSE** on error.

Comment: I didn't notice the type before the function. :( Ok. Let's forget this question ever existed. I've learn today that, I can see the return type on the PHP manual. :D~

Comment: But it should have been `mixed` since it can return `FALSE` too; `0 !== false`.

Comment: @jensgram maybe the types written on php manual presuppose the type on success only? Perhaps? I'm guessing...

Comment: @MEM Could be. I don't know, either :-S

Comment: @jensgram Almost all functions return FALSE when they fail and return NULL when wrong arguments are given. The return value type is documented for success, otherwise everything would be mixed.

Comment: @Artefacto Sounds reasonable :)

Answer (score 1):

An integer, or boolean false on failure.

```
$fh = fopen('/tmp/bar', 'w');
$bytes = fwrite($fh, 'Hello, world.');

var_dump($bytes); // output: int(13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the case that `fwrite` returns **NULL** with `E_NOTICE` error.
Probably this occurs when **network stream aborted**.

```
Notice: fwrite(): in .... on line ....
```